# Volatile variable change lag between threads in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio, audio, audiotrack

I would like to preface this by claiming that I am very new to android studio and java (and even this level programming in general). I am working on a simple audio synthesis application, and I was testing how multiple threads would work so that I could synthesize music and hold down multiple keys at once rather than pressing a key, calculating the entire audio buffer, and playing it once.

Here's the setup: I have 25 keys (view/buttons), that I can detect when they are pressed down and lifted up in my main UI thread. My second thread then constantly runs in the background and constantly calculates the audio buffer, and passes it to the AudioTrack stream to play. If no keys are pressed, it simply passes it a zero buffer so that nothing gets played essentially.

Here is the problem: I have set up a volatile array to represent which keys are pressed, so that when a button gets pressed in my app on the tablet, it sets an appropriate flag in the boolean array. My second thread then should be able to use that array to further calculate the audio buffer. Currently, I have it setup for 25 keys, but have only linked 2 keys in my UI, so it only recognizes when 2 of them are pressed, and the other 25 are simply set to zero. The second thread is able to recognize when either one or both of the keys are pressed, but there is a lag. In my main UI thread, I have set it up where it changes the color of the key when it detects a touch event, and that responds immediately, but the sound playing starts after a while. However, I can tap the key quickly, and it will detect the two events such as touch down and release (indicated by the keys changing color), but its as if the second thread did not recognize that I pressed the key, as it does not play the sound for even a brief moment (milliseconds). It seems like there is a few hundred millisecond lag between the key press being registered between the two threads. However, I think that the volatile boolean array keyPress does change the variable quickly, because if it didn't, then even with the lag, the second thread would play the sound for a brief second. But rather, it seems like the main UI thread changes the appropriate keyPress array element to true when a key is pressed, and also sets it to false when I lift my finger, but I can somehow do this without the second thread recognizing this happened? How is this possible? Is the main thread not actually changing the volatile array properly quick enough? Like it recognizes that a key is pressed, changes the local cached copy of the variable, and then changes the volatile variable? What would cause this lag? Is it based on the nature of the loops I have formed in the second threadLoop() thread? I don't think the thread is too slow for computing a sound buffer, because it doesn't break up the sound between buffers, so I don't think that is the problem.

I should also mention that I am not sure if "volatile" is the best variable type to use here either, so if there's some other data type, or something else I should be using, please let me know. I looked a little bit into Handlers and Loopers, but I thought that wasn't required here because those queue the tasks while I want keyPresses to be detected by the thread responsible for playing audio instantly (and also because it was kinda hard for me to wrap my head around them so I didn't bother with it, but if you think I am doing it incorrectly with this method of using a thread, please let me know). I am also using a Lenovo tab M10 in case that is relevant information. If there is any more information you would like from me, please let me know, and if a similar post already exists (I couldn't find something that answered my exact question), please point me in the right direction. Thank you very much for your help!

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private boolean isActive = false;

    private Thread audioThread;

    volatile boolean[] keyPress = new boolean[25];
    //volatile boolean keypress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Arrays.fill(keyPress, false);
        //keypress = false;

        final View c4 = (View) findViewById(R.id.c4);
        final View d4 = (View) findViewById(R.id.d4);

        c4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                int action = motionEvent.getAction();//.getActionMasked(motionEvent);
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    c4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ed1b24")); //"#81DAF5"
                    keyPress[0] = true;
                    //keypress = true;
                    //audioThread.start();
                }

                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    c4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    keyPress[0] = false;
                    //keypress = false;
                    //audioThread.stop();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        d4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                int action = motionEvent.getAction();//.getActionMasked(motionEvent);
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    d4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ed1b24")); //"#81DAF5"
                    keyPress[1] = true;
                    //audioThread.start();
                }

                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    d4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    keyPress[1] = false;
                    //audioThread.stop();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                threadLoop();
            }
        }).start();


    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void threadLoop(){

        AudioTrack audioTrack;
        int intBufferSize;
        short[] shortAudioData;
        int intSampleRate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        intBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(intSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        shortAudioData = new short[intBufferSize];

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                intSampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                intBufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(intSampleRate);



        int n = 0;
        float x;
        float TS = 1.0f/intSampleRate;
        float freq = 440.0f;
        float PI = 3.14159f;
        float omega = 2.0f*PI*freq*TS;
        int numKeysPressed;

        int incrementer = shortAudioData.length;

        audioTrack.play();
        while(true){

            for(int i = 0; i < incrementer; ++i){
                if(n == Integer.MAX_VALUE | n < 0){
                    n = 0;
                }
                x = 0;
                numKeysPressed = 0;
                for(int a = 0; a < 25; ++a){
                    if(keyPress[a] == true) {
                        x += (float) (Math.sin((float) (omega * n*(a+1))));
                        numKeysPressed++;
                    }
                }
                x = (float)(x/numKeysPressed);
                ++n;
                shortAudioData[i] = (short)(x * Short.MAX_VALUE);
            }


            audioTrack.write(shortAudioData, 0, shortAudioData.length);
        }

        //audioTrack.stop();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the problem:

```
volatile boolean[] keyPress = new boolean[25];
```

What that declares is a volatile variable containing a reference to an array.  The volatile semantics apply to to the *variable* that contains the reference.  Not to the array that it refers to.

That means that when you assign to a cell of the array that `keyPressed` refers to, there is not going to be an write to the (volatile) variable itself.  Therefore, there is no cache flush (or whatever) to guarantee that another thread will see the update to the array cell.

(A more technically accurate explanation entails the discussion of the *happens before* relationships, but the outcome is the same.)

---

One alternative would be to use an atomic array class.  For example, you could use an `AtomicIntegerArray` where each `int` encodes a truth value:

```
// (This needs to be 'final' ... to guarantee that the keypress
// variable is visible without any additional synchronization.)
final AtomicIntegerArray keyPress = new AtomicIntegerArray(25);

// To test if a flag is set:
if (keyPress.get(i) != 0) {
    // it is set.
}

// To set a flag (atomically)
keyPress.set(i, flag ? 0 : 1);
```

And you can do other things like atomically toggling or atomically incrementing (a counter) by using other [api methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html).

An `AtomicReferenceArray<Boolean>` would also work.  I'll leave you to figure out the details.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my main post, but I originally tried it with just a boolean variable and one key being pressed. Would what you mentioned above still apply to a single boolean variable and not an array, because the "lag" I see when pressing a key and for sound to be produced is essentially consistent whether if I have a volatile array or a volatile boolean. Thanks for the answer though. I will certainly try it out with the Atomic array and see if it fixes my cause, and perhaps update the post if it does fix it, or the issue persists.